# Linux Distribution with G++ installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-construction, g++, offline

I am having a bit of a nightmare running up an Ubuntu distribution on an offline machine.  Can anyone advise a distribution of Linux with G++ (or the contents of the build essential ubuntu package) as standard?

It is an absolute nightmare trying to download all the dependencies separately and I'm not getting on with Keryx at all.  Many people have noted that build-essential package is available on the Ubuntu install CD but I can't find it on the 12.04 install CD using

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

To those trying to close the question: This is programming related, I'm trying to get hold of g++ - comes under tools.

Comment: That's because `apt-get install` needs to use the internet.

Comment: Incorrect, apt-get is supposed to be able to read packages from any source, including CD

Comment: Can you build an identical system that is connected to the internet and copy the apt cache dir?

Comment: @robert Assume I have no access to an online Linux machine

Comment: @trickdev have you looked at http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/12.04/release/?  The "Install/Live DVD" should have many more packages.

Comment: I hadn't tried the DVD, only the Live CD.  Downloading now, I will post back once I've tried it.

Comment: It is _not_ programming related. It is related to installing an OS and programming tools in specific circumstances. Nowhere does it say: "why does my code not work", "how can I proceed here, where I am stuck". See [SU]